# mi primer virtualhost

Tags: php, apache, backend

Hola muy buenas para todos siempre he intentado montar un virtual host y siempre me da error Abajo colocare el contenido de mi htaccess para ver si alguno me indica que esta mal en el log error me sale VirtualHost not allowed here
cabe destacar que no se me cambian las rutas de los error log , transferlog o DocumentRoot

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.17-0\apache2\htdocs\public
ServerAdmin israelhugggug@gmail.com
ServerName mivhost.com
ErrorLog error_log
TransferLog access_log

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName sinave.localhost

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/user/proyecto/web
 <Directory /home/user/proyecto/web/ > 
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
            AllowOverride all 
            Require all granted
    #Order allow,deny 
            allow from all 
    </Directory> 


LogLevel warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

El DocumenteRoot va la ruta a tu proyecto donde tienes tu index.php
tambien debes modificar los hthost para que al ingresar la direccion sinave.localhost responda a tu localhost

Comment: ¿como se crea la ruta relativa que voy a poner en el document root?¿parte del htaccess?

Comment: ya lo descubri parte del ServerRoot siempre y cuando la ruta sea relativa